# Xcode Kurdish localization issue

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

I have a localized Kurdish text in google sheet when I copy the text from the sheet to the localization files, Kurdish characters are looking weird.

From the sheet:
[image]

From Xcode:
[image]

I tried to use Kurdish fonts maybe it will fix the issue but it didn't work

More Updates:
If I use Kurdish (ku) the file text looks fine, and if I use Central Kurdish (ckb, ckb-IQ, ckb-IR) the text is not fine

Any suggestion what should I do?

Comment: you need to have utf-8 file format

Comment: @xiarnousx didn't work

Comment: Found a solution for this? Having the very same trouble.